# Applying Orthographic projection or frustum effecting normalised coordinates?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, coordinates, coordinate-systems, orthographic

I know that normalised coordinates should be -1 (Left) and +1 (Right) and -1 (Bottom) and +1 (Top)

like this:

[image]

But after applying this:

**From my onSurfaceChanged method**

```
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
float ratio = (float) width / height;
Matrix.orthoM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

//The above line can be replaced with:
//Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
//But I get the same results with either frustumM or otrhoM
```

**And this in my onDrawFrame method**

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
```

(I then pass mMVPMatrix into my custom class's draw method where it is rotated and translated).

But, my co-ordinates seem to change - this is roughly what happens:

[image]

As you can see, the x co-ordinates are altered somewhat, -1 and +1 are no longer the edges of the screen (on the device I'm using at the moment, the outer edges become -1.7 and +1.7)

Y coordinates remain unchanged.

Would appreciate if someone could point out where I'm going wrong?  I need it to be -1 through +1 like it should be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my eyes it appears correct. If your screen is not a square, then are you sure you want your x axis to be stretched so it behaves like a square screen? Because if you do that, then if you tell OpenGL to draw a square, it will appear as a rectangle on the screen instead if you don't have your x axis edges be larger than your y axis edges when your screen width is wider than your screen height, as suggested by the image. That's why you pass your `ratio` to the projection, so it knows how to draw things properly.

What is happening when you draw a regular square on the screen? Is it appearing as a square or a rectangle?

Comment: Hmmmm yeah I see what you mean now, I'v written a quad rendering method where you pass in co-ordinates (like drawQuad(x,y)) where x & y are specified as 'normal' screen coords (with 0,0 at upper left).  The method then converts these so they can be drawn.  But, since applying the projection, if I specify 0,0 it doesn't get drawn at top left anymore if you see what I mean so I'm trying to understand in order to fix this.  Basically if I specify 0 as an X coord, then I need the rendering method to somehow interpret that as the left side of the screen. Unless there;s an easier way to do that.....

Comment: Thanks for the answer though it explains it well. I will ask another question regarding developing for different res/ratios.  I'm used to developing by scaling my sprites based on screen width and height so they appear the same size relative to any screen. (ie, the game appears the same size no matter what res or ratio screen the game is run on) - but I see people talking a lot about 'showing more of the game area' on wider screens which is a concept I'm finding difficult to grasp.